# Python's FTP library connects to an IP but not its domain

Tags: python, ftp, ftplib

I'm using ftplib's FTP class to connect to ftp://emi.nasdaq.com. Using the domain doesn't work, but using FileZilla I can see the IP address the domain name resolves to, and the IP address works.

```
def main():
print("Grabbing data...")
with FTP() as ftp:
    ftp.connect('ftp://emi.nasdaq.com', 21)
```

Specifically, the domain throws a GAIError ([Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed). I'm using Python 3.8. How can I resolve the domain to its IP before passing it to the FTP class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`ftplib` docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ftplib.html) suggest to use address without leading `ftp://` I did

```
from ftplib import FTP
ftp = FTP()
ftp.connect('emi.nasdaq.com',21)
ftp.login()
ftp.retrlines('LIST')
ftp.quit()
```

and output was

```
07-27-13  04:30PM       <DIR>          aspnet_client
03-21-13  09:31AM       <DIR>          Baltic
07-21-21  02:42PM       <DIR>          Basic_NLS
05-21-19  08:29AM       <DIR>          Index
07-21-21  02:44PM       <DIR>          ITCH
08-21-20  02:07PM       <DIR>          Nasdaq Canada
08-05-19  09:31AM       <DIR>          Nordic
07-19-21  10:11AM       <DIR>          Options
12-01-20  09:49AM       <DIR>          Test
07-27-21  10:26AM       <DIR>          Web Based Reports
09-09-21  05:38PM                  168 web.config
```